# How to send file and filename through socket in C?

Tags: c, sockets

I am trying to send a file and its name through a socket in C.

The relevant server code is:

```
char file[18];
    memset(file, 0, 18);
    file[17] = '\0';
    int recvd =  recv(newsock, file, 16, 0);

char local_file_path[200];
memset(local_file_path, 0, 200);

if(recvd == -1 || recv == 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "File name not received");
    continue;
}

strcat(local_file_path, "/home/ubuntu/results/");
strcat(local_file_path, file);
FILE* fp = fopen(local_file_path, "wb");

char buffer[4096];
while(1)
{
    recvd =  recv(newsock, buffer, 4096, 0);
    fwrite(buffer, sizeof(char), recvd, fp);
    if(recvd == -1 || recvd == 0) {
        fclose(fp);
        break;
    }
}
close(newsock);
}
close(servSock);
```

The relevant client code is:

```
char* my_16_long_fname = "filename1234.txt"
int ret = send(sock, my_16_long_file_fname, strlen(my_16_long_fname), 0)
```

This code, however, has been creating lots of undefined behaviour such as:
1.Receiving garbage filenames filled with garbage
2.Receiving empty files (so a name with nothing inside - could be some other bug but possibly due to this)

I have thought about a few solutions:

1.Diferentiate file types by signature/header and generate a file name on the server side. Besides this being a cheap solution which doesn't teach me how to actually solve the problem, it doesn't work with the logic i'm using, where sometimes I send error codes instead of file names after opening the socket.

2.Iterate over the recv'd buffer on the first call to recv until I encounter a '\0' character. Then write the remainder of the buffer as binary data and keep on receiving data as usual.

Is this the most efficient/simplest and solid solution to this issue, which will prevent any undefined behaviour?

Comment: I think you shouldn't differentiate filename and data in two different calls to `recv`.
Add a header, filename and data to a buffer and send it from the client in a single loop. On server side, receive data in a single loop as well. Another function should accumulate what's been received and then interpret what is filename and what is data based on a header for example.

Comment: Alright, I'll apply that, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way your current code could possibly work. If the filename is always one character, your code can read too many characters. If your filename is always the same number of characters but more than one character, your code can read too few characters. If the filename is a variable number of characters, your code could read a smaller number than was sent.

So there is no sending protocol for which this could be valid receiving code.

Until you are an expert on writing networking code, *always* follow these two steps:

1. Document the protocol.

How many bytes does the filename occupy? Is it a fixed number or a variable number? Is it always followed by a zero byte?

2. Implement the protocol.

For example, your code reads up to 16 bytes for the filename. But it never checks if it received the whole file name. What if it only received a single byte?

Comment: The problem I can see is that recv receives 16 bytes and afterwards a '\0' is added. However, the string sent also contains a null character, which might be interpreted later on as file data, causing corruption. I can see how this code is gimmicky in general and I agree with you. Should I go with solution 2 or is tweaking my current code enough?

Comment: @coolguy123 It's hard to say without understanding your intention. Is the filename always suppose to be exactly 16 characters sent/received? If so, change your code to receive *exactly* 16 characters instead of up to 16 characters.

Comment: Yes it is always exactly 16 characters. Or a char* with 16 chars. But if there is a nul terminating char at the end I think that could cause some problems.

Comment: @coolguy123 David is saying you need to sit down and work out what to send and how to receive it, keeping in mind that one send doesn't equal one recv - TCP can run sends together or split them apart. One simple idea would be to use the null character to mean the end of the filename, so then you receive the filename by reading one character at a time (or more if you are clever enough) until you get a null character, then everything after that is file data. Another idea is to always send 16 bytes for the filename. Another idea is to send the length of the filename first, in one byte.